# Maximum Whoosh Index size?

Tags: python, indexing, whoosh

I'm using a 32-bit Ubuntu machine. I'm trying to create a Whoosh index of a 27GB file. But my system is crashing after index size of 3GB.
 Is there any size constraint on Whoosh index size? If not then what can be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that Whoosh overflows to RAM of your computer by loading the 27Gb file?

Comment: I'm not loading the whole file in memory at once. I'm not getting any memory related exception. My system just get stuck.